# Confusion in the statement of Zorn's Lemma

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

The statement of Zorn's lemma in the book "Modern methods of mathematical physics: Vol $1$" by Simon and Reed reads as follows:

*Let $X$ be a nonempty partially ordered set with the property that every linearly ordered subset has an upper bound in $X$. Then each linearly ordered set has some upper bound that is also a maximal element of $X$.*

I am confused about what does the second sentence mean. Does it mean that every linearly ordered subset of $X$ has a common upper bound which is the maximal element?

Comment: See [Zorn's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma#Statement_of_the_lemma): "the set $X$ contains at least one maximal element."

Comment: There is a distinction between a maximal element and a greatest element. It is a pretty important distinction when working with partially ordered sets.

Comment: It means that for all totally ordered subsets $S\subseteq X$ there is some maximal element of $X$ which is a upper bound for $S$, not that there is some maximal element of $X$ which is an upper bound of all totally ordered subsets of $X$.

Answer (score 3):

No. It means that **if** *every linearly ordered subset [read: chain] has an upper bound*, it does not have to be within that chain (although it could be if the chain has a largest point), **then** *there is a maximal element in the entire order*.

Recall that maximal simply means that there is no strictly larger elements in the order, it does not mean largest.

For example, if you consider $V$ to be a vector space over some field, say $\Bbb R$, then we can look at the partial order of all linearly independent subsets of $V$. We can verify that given a chain of linearly independent sets, its union is also linearly independent. It does not necessarily mean that the chain has a largest element, but it could be. Zorn's Lemma says that this partial order has a maximal element, and we can prove that any such maximal element is a basis for $V$. But we can easily replace one basis element by a different one (e.g. if $v$ is in the basis, we can replace it by $2v$), so you can see that this maximal is very much non-unique.

Comment: Well, it says a little more than *there is a maximal element in the entire order*; it says that for any given chain, we can choose the maximal element to be an upper bound of that chain.

Comment: No. That is not what Zorn's Lemma says. That is a consequence.

Comment: It might not be what Zorn's Lemma says, but it's what Simon & Reed says it says, which is what the OP asked about.